# Why would payload optimized weight make a difference for bin space

Tags: payload

I was on a Delta flight out of DTW and they told people (about 30 times at the gate and in the plane) that the flight is payload optimized and people needed to make sure they didn't put anything but a small carry on in the bin.

Why would this matter? The weight will be the same no matter where you put the luggage on the plane. Does vertical weight above the center of mass matter?

Comment: It's to prevent [side-fumbling of the turbo encabulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_encabulator). Sometimes, these silly officious announcements have far less basis in any technical necessity than in simply "hurry up, get in, sit down, and use the space at your feet before taking up limited space in the overhead bin," since if the latter runs out, the cabin crew has to gate-check any left-over bags, and that's extra work & extra time. "Payload optimized" sounds like techno babble to me - meant to sound impressive, but void of actual meaning.